# role based login in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

Roles are employee and admin. i have created api that is generating token now i want to add roles on login means if employee logged in he should be directed towards respective pages and admin should be directed towards respective pages.
I have created separate table for roles now i want to know how the things work and how to add roles with the login credentials.to join the register table with roles in order to login i am using a mutual column which is **internal_id**.
[image]

here is the employee table
[image]

here is my API which i created in nodejs.

```
 login: (req, res ) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    getUserByUserEmail(body.email, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(!results) {
            return res.json({
                success : 0 ,
                message : "Invalid Email or Password"
            });
        }

        const result = compareSync( body.password, results[0].password);
        if (result) {
            results.password = undefined;
            const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, "qwe123", {expiresIn : "3h"});
            return res.json({
                success : 1 ,
                message : "Login Succesfully!",
                token : jsontoken
            });
        }
        else{
            return res.json({
                success : 0 ,
                message : "Invalid Email or Password"
            });
        }
    });

 }
```

this is the code how i am getting email and password from employee table.

```
getUserByUserEmail  : (email , callBack) =>{
    pool.query(
        `select * from employee where email = ? `,
        [email],
        (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error){
               
                return callBack(error);
            }
            return callBack(null, results);
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Anybody help me with the nodejs API to map role with the login credentials?

Answer (score 1):

As a security consideration, I would like to suggest that your SQL query `select * from employee where email = ?` be more *specific* and only retrieve the information you need, e.g.: `select internal_id, password from employee where email = ?`

As regards your mapping of roles: I won't provide a code-for-you. But using the stored **internal_id** you retrieved when authenticating, add a function like `getRoleByUserID` where you search `select role from roles where internal_id = ?, [stored_id_from_auth_query]`. Then run a case or if/else statements to generate your view based on the returned role.